# Azure Backup fails after installing Kaspersky Total Security

Tags: azure, backup

Since installing Kaspersky Total Security two days ago, my Azure backups keep failing. This is the process: Taking snapshot of volumes; Preparing storage; Estimating size of backup items; job failed. The error message for each volume is 'unable to find changes in a file. This could be due to various reasons (0x07EF8).
Data in my files has definitely been changing. I have tried two things: 1. Disabled Kaspersky. 2. Completely deleted the backup and rebuilt from scratch. This made no difference at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try to exclude all VHD files and adding cbengine.exe to the Trusted applications list, see this article:

http://www.cantrell.co/blog/2016/3/21/microsoft-azure-backup-feat-kaspersky

Comment: Done that but it still failed. N.B. I excluded the Folder VHD. Should I have saved each individual file within the folder?

Comment: Later: found how to include all files within the folder ( put * at the end of the folder name). Backup still fails.